# Sign in to access website (gateway authentication?)

Tags: networking, router, internet, connection, gateway

I recently moved to a new apartment, and I have an Internet plan that is included.
For this, they use a stick connected to the house LAN plug, and it provides WIFI with other services.

But the stick is slow, and the WIFI is poor, so I connected my own router and added a LAN cable to my computer.

I set up everything and I am connected to the router, but when I access some website (HTTP website only ?), I get prompted that the connection is not secured and I need to log in to some IP `10.5.43.1`. Same with phones and others, they are connected but prompt `not connected to the internet` even though some pages do work.

I tried to understand what is the `10.5.43.1` and I think it's the building gateway (but not sure)

I asked the company to know the ids to connect, but they say they can't help. 'You should just be able to plug the router and it should work' and that 'they can't provide support for setup my own router' so I need to find the solution by myself.

I believe the problem is not on my end, my PC => ROUTER works, is the ROUTER => Internet that is flawed. I wanted to know if you have any idea how to solve such a problem

[image]

Is it something I have to set up on the router? is it something I have to ask the apartment for?

Comment: Difficult to say from the information you provided; they may have a captive portal (google) for http/https in their installation. The "stick" they give you may have the username/password built in.

Comment: Yeah, I think there is not much help I can get it here as it is something hard to explain over a forum. I will try to check the stick settings and investigate further, thanks